# Python: get maximum value object for unique key

Tags: python, algorithm, list, logic

I have the following list of items:

```
[
    {'country' : 'India', 'date' : '18-Mar-14'},
    {'country' : 'India', 'date' : '18-Apr-14'},
    {'country' : 'India', 'date' : '18-May-14'},
    {'country' : 'Australia', 'date' : '18-Mar-14'},
    {'country' : 'Australia', 'date' : '18-Apr-14'},
    {'country' : 'Australia', 'date' : '18-May-14'},
    {'country' : 'China', 'date' : '18-Mar-14'},
    {'country' : 'China', 'date' : '18-Apr-14'},
    {'country' : 'China', 'date' : '18-May-14'}
]
```

How can I obtain only those items containing maximum date value for each country i.e for each country it returns the item containing that country with the largest date. In this instance, the result list would be:

```
[
    {'country' : 'India', 'date' : '18-May-14'},
    {'country' : 'Australia', 'date' : '18-May-14'},
    {'country' : 'China', 'date' : '18-May-14'},
]
```

Comment: Can you clarify "largest date"? Did you mean "most recent"?

Comment: Group by countries, and then take the "largest date" from that group

Comment: yes the most recent date. What would be the most efficient way with best complexity because my data is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop and track the maximum value found so far per country. You'll have to parse those dates into `datetime` objects so that you can easily compare them:

```
from datetime import datetime

max_dates = {}
for entry in list_of_dicts:
    date = datetime.strptime(entry['date'], '%d-%b-%y')
    country = entry['country']
    if country not in max_dates or date > max_dates[country][0]:
        max_dates[country] = (date, entry)

result = [entry for date, entry in max_dates.values()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> list_of_dicts = [
...     {'country' : 'India', 'date' : '18-Mar-14'},
...     {'country' : 'India', 'date' : '18-Apr-14'},
...     {'country' : 'India', 'date' : '18-May-14'},
...     {'country' : 'Australia', 'date' : '18-Mar-14'},
...     {'country' : 'Australia', 'date' : '18-Apr-14'},
...     {'country' : 'Australia', 'date' : '18-May-14'},
...     {'country' : 'China', 'date' : '18-Mar-14'},
...     {'country' : 'China', 'date' : '18-Apr-14'},
...     {'country' : 'China', 'date' : '18-May-14'}
... ]
>>> max_dates = {}
>>> for entry in list_of_dicts:
...     date = datetime.strptime(entry['date'], '%d-%b-%y')
...     country = entry['country']
...     if country not in max_dates or date > max_dates[country][0]:
...         max_dates[country] = (date, entry)
... 
>>> [entry for date, entry in max_dates.values()]
[{'date': '18-May-14', 'country': 'China'}, {'date': '18-May-14', 'country': 'Australia'}, {'date': '18-May-14', 'country': 'India'}]
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  ValueError: time data '%e-%b-%y' does not match format '1-Mar-12'. Any idea why?

Comment: @Tarun: Use the updated version; I had mixed up the arguments of `strptime()` in the first revision.

Answer (score 0):

You could map month names to corresponding numbers from 1 to 12, then split the date attribute of each country by (-) and compare the numbers of the day, month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Or in one line:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime

[(x,max(y,key=lambda o:datetime.strptime(o['date'], '%d-%b-%y'))) for x,y in groupby(sorted(t, key=lambda o: o['country']), key=lambda o: o['country'])]
```